# Does minimization of console application will affect the performance?

Tags: windows, console

These days I'm doing a performance test on windows server 2003. I wrote a console application to test it. I found the performance will get much better if I minimized the command window. Before Minimization, every operation cost about 1.9ms. After minization, every operation cost about 1.5ms. This is a rather big difference.

Why the difference is so big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console output is one area that may be impacted - no need to draw anything till window is visible could make big differnce (especially when there is a lot of output).

Comment: thank you, I found I have print an empty line that not noticed before.